# MySQL - Binary Log File size growing more than the maximum limit

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, binlog

I have a MySQL 5.7 running on a Centos 6. I enabled Binary Logging and didn't provide any custom value for the maximum size of Binary Log in my configuration file. By default, the parameter **max_binlog_size = 1073741824** which is equivalent to 1GB. This means, once a binary log reaches the size of 1GB, a new file should be created.

I observed in my server that all the binary log files are of different sizes with lot of contrast like 200GB, 165GB, 4GB etc...

Why does this happen when the maximum size is 1GB for a binary log file? Is it necessary to mention even the default maximum size explicitly in the configuration file?

Comment: Let's see `ls -l` of those huge files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason your binary logs are so gigantic is simple: YOU ARE COMMITTING TOO MUCH DATA PER SINGLE TRANSACTION !!! Why is this the case ? According to the MySQL Documentation on [max_binlog_size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_max_binlog_size):

> A transaction is written in one chunk to the binary log, so it is never split between several binary logs. **Therefore, if you have big transactions, you might see binary log files larger than [max_binlog_size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_max_binlog_size)**.

## SUGGESTION

Please try to commit data in smaller chunks.

Comment: `store binary logs on fast HDDs (not on SSDs) for faster write performance` ?! Are you serious about that?! Even the worst SSD will outperform any HDD (10k or 15k) on the market in both RANDOM WRITE or READ and IOPS. For instance, my SSD on the server can achieve 100k IOPS for READ, while fast 10k SAS drive can only about 1k. HDD's are simply limited by physics for random I/O.

Comment: @stamster For bare metal machines, I am drop dead serious. SSDs will age faster than HDD’s in the long run. Cloud providers like Amazon and Google will not provide decent HDD‘s

Comment: @stamster binary logs are always written sequentially. They should go on a different disk at least, apart from the data. Data should go on SSD drives (where random writes can flourish for data) while binary logs should go to another drive whether it is HDD or SSD

Comment: Who ever mentioned drives aging / longevity? That's out of consideration when we're discussing DB performance here. You stated that HDD's are better for RDBMS binary logs workload - and now you have explained your statement with binary logs being sequential. Well, that's whole another story and perspective and I can agree with you that logs shall at least go onto dedicated drive(s). And yes - being sequential data it's OK to go onto mechanical disks. And some folks even advise to disable completely MySQL/MariaDB binary logs. Even I did it once to minimize I/O on the primary SAS 10K drives.

Comment: I suspect that "use HDD for logs" is an old wives tale that no longer applies.  (But I don't have any proof either way.)

Answer (score 1):

If the files are indeed too large, you might consider changing
the binlog_expire_logs_seconds configuration:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_binlog_expire_logs_seconds

By default, it is set to keep the logs files for 30 days.
so you might get many files of 1GB...
setting the value to a smaller value (7 days for example) will reduce the total size the binary logs will require.

Once the configuration is set, you'll need to restart the server, and Mysql will clear the old files automitically.