# Maximum overall size of MariaDB binary logs

Tags: mysql, mariadb, binlog

I am looking for a way to prevent MariaDB binary logs from taking a huge size when they grow faster than usual.

- variable [max_binlog_size](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/replication-and-binary-log-server-system-variables/#max_binlog_size) set the maximum size of ONE binary logfile.
- variable [expire_log_days](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/replication-and-binary-log-server-system-variables/#expire_logs_days) set the number of days after which the binary logs are removed.

But is there a way to set a "**maximum overall size**" of ALL binary log files? or, maybe simpler, a maximum number of binary log files, which would overload *expire_log_days* retention...

Answer (score 9):

## [max_binlog_size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_max_binlog_size)

With regards to [max_binlog_size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_max_binlog_size), what you are asking is not possible. Why ?

On `May 05, 2017`, I answered the question [MySQL - Binary Log File size growing more than the maximum limit](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/172807/mysql-binary-log-file-size-growing-more-than-the-maximum-limit/172821#172821). I mentioned the following from the MySQL Documentation on [max_binlog_size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_max_binlog_size):

> A transaction is written in one chunk to the binary log, so it is never split between several binary logs. **Therefore, if you have big transactions, you might see binary log files larger than [max_binlog_size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_max_binlog_size)**.

That fact that your binary logs are bigger than [max_binlog_size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_max_binlog_size) just indicates that you are writing too many changes per single transaction.

## [expire_logs_days](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_expire_logs_days)

With regards to [expire_logs_days](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_expire_logs_days), the granularity is in days. There is nothing you can do with that.

If you wish to squeeze the number of binlogs down, you may have do one of two things:

**SUGGESTION #1** : Scan in the binlog index file, find the last 10 binlogs, get the first binlog of those 10, and run something like:

```
PURGE BINARY LOGS TO 'whatever-binlog.002316';
```

**SUGGESTION #2** : Write a cronjob that will keep the last 18 hours of binary logs:

```
PURGE BINARY LOGS BEFORE (NOW() - INTERVAL 18 HOUR);
```

**GIVE IT A TRY !!!**

Comment: Thanks. I think MySQL/MariaDB lacks an option like "max_binlog_files" that would delete the oldest binlog files when it exceeds this maximum.

Comment: In MySql 8, don't use `expire_logs_days`, use `expire_logs_seconds` instead. https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=10924

Answer (score 2):

I just noticed that Percona Server has implemented such a system variable "max_binlog_files":

https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/LATEST/flexibility/max_binlog_files.html

MariaDB has an opened issue for backporting it to MariaDB Server, in "open" status at this time:

https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-13188

Comment: Now, that's cool !!! +1 for max_binlog_files !!!

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:  No.

Long answer(s):

Why do you want this?  Running out of disk space?  If so, then you are threatening to crash for other reasons.  That is, we need to discuss the bigger picture.

Are you frequently `UPDATEing` all rows of a big table (with Row Based Replication)?  That can quickly bloat the binlogs.  Let's discuss alternatives to that form of `UPDATE`.  (Need table and query specifics to continue this approach.)  A big `DELETE` could also bloat the binlog(s) fast.

If you now have `max_binlog_size` set to 1G, changing it to 100M could shrink the disk usage by 900M *in some situations*.  (I see no down-side to making the change.)

Comment: I am using Mixed Based Replication (=> leads to Stmt most of the time). My binlog size is 100MB. I encountered a situation where the application wrote a huge amount of data in just a few hours that exceeded 100GB of binlog storage...

Comment: @NicolasPayart - Ouch!  That's a good stunt.  bugs.mysql.com accepts "feature requests".