# Rotation of bin.log file

Tags: mysql, log

I am trying to change the binary log rotation from days to hours. By default there is an option only for days in the MySQL config file: expire_logs_days.

Is there any way to change the binary log rotation from days to hours or even minutes?

I am running MySQL version 5.7.23 on Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 1):

Only a days option exists.

[binlog_row_image=minimal](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_binlog_row_image) might help save some space.

Getting more storage is a better long term solution.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to get binlog rotation in hours is to script it

Here is the code

```
#!/bin/bash
HRS=16
mysql -uroot -prootpass -e"PURGE BINARY LOGS BEFORE NOW() - INTERVAL ${HRS} HOUR"
```

Put this code in a script called `/root/mybinlog_rotate.sh`

Make sure you run `chmod +x /root/mybinlog_rotate.sh`

Add that script in the crontab to rotate every 30 min

```
0,30 * * * * /root/mybinlog_rotate.sh
```

This is a little heavy handed but it can be done

I suggested this months ago : [Maximum overall size of MariaDB binary logs](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/194469/maximum-overall-size-of-mariadb-binary-logs/194477#194477)

Answer (score 1):

If, by "rotation", you mean creating a new binlog, then decrease the value of `max_binlog_size`.  It defaults to 1G or 100M (depending on the version).  10M would have it creating smaller new files more frequently.

If you mean purging old binlogs, then set `expire_log_days` (in old versions) to a small number, such as 1.  Then binlogs older than 1 day will be deleted at some point.

In MySQL 8.0, it is `binlog_expire_logs_seconds`:

> Added the binlog_expire_logs_seconds system variable, which sets an interval in seconds for purging of the binary log. The effects of this variable and expire_logs_days are cumulative, making it possible to set a period such as 1.5 days. To completely disable automatic binary log purging, set both variables equal to 0, which is the default value for both of them. (Bug #71697, Bug #18260088)

It is OK to change both the size and the expire.  After changing the config file, restart the server.

Comment: `expire_log_days` should be `expire_logs_days`